# Optimisation problem to maximise profit of fleet allocation given profitability matrix of plane type to route & constraint of block hrs

Tags: r, optimization, tree, roi

I am trying to create an optimisation algorithm to allocate plane types to most efficiently to my routes for fleet optimisation.

My input: a 150 x 6 matrix, with 150 routes which must all be flown, and 6 possible plane types, with the variables being profit per route. As constraints I have the number of block hours per route that must be used (to meet the demand) and the maximum number of block hours per plane type. The output should be a 150 x 6 matrix that tells me which plane should be flown for how many hours on which route.

I have tried a tree and a linear ROI optimisation but unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: IMHO, the best approach is first to write down the mathematical model. Once you have that, the implementation is much easier.